# What is the exact difference between AWS artifactId secretsmanager and aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

What are the differences between the below-secret manager dependencies and when to use what?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>secretsmanager</artifactId>
  <version>${aws-api.version-2}</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.549</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS Java SDK that uses the `software.amazon.awssdk` package name is Version 2 of the AWS SDK for Java.

The one that uses the `com.amazonaws` package name is Version 1 of the AWS SDK for Java.